Make gemini-1.5-flash-002 accesible for my GCloud Run project
I am trying a basic script to summarize text:
def generate(self, text_to_summarize):
    vertexai.init(project="<PROJECT_ID", location="MY_REGION")
    model = GenerativeModel(
        "gemini-1.5-flash-002",
        system_instruction=[my_prompt]
    )
    responses = model.generate_content(
        [text_to_summarize],
        stream=True,
    )

    for response in responses:
        print(response.text, end="")

This works as intended locally, using "gemini-1.5-flash-002"
In order to run in gcloud run, I have built the script in a docker container and have deployed it to gcloud run.
Calling the endpoint then fails with error:
"PermissionDenied(\"Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/<REGION>/publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-flash-002' (or it may not exist).\")"

I have double-checked permissions with gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT-ID> and see:
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-<CODE>@gcp-sa-vertex-op.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/aiplatform.onlinePredictionServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-<CODE>@gcp-sa-aiplatform.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/aiplatform.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:<CODE>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:<MY-EMAIL>
  role: roles/aiplatform.user
...

I checked the models here and aiplatform.endpoints.predict is a permission for roles/aiplatform.user, so I have permission.
This has led me to conclude the model does not exist. I thought gcloud run would automatically use the gemini flash one as it does locally. I have run
gcloud ai models list --region=<REGION>
and there are no models.
Even trying to deploy that model to my endpoint fails. The code to deploy is:
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model <MY-ENDPOINT-ID>\
   --model=gemini-1.5-flash-002 \
   --region=<REGION> \
   --display-name="flash-deployment" \
   --machine-type="n1-standard-4"

and this fails with
(gcloud.ai.endpoints.deploy-model) There is an error while getting the model information. Please make sure the model 'projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/<REGION>/models/gemini-1.5-flash-002' exists.

I think I have to register the model somewhere, but when I open the model registry and try to "Create" one, it asks me for training data and so on. I do not want to train a new model, just use the flash pretrained one.
Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Did you check your libraries version? You could have an older version locally than in your requirement.txt when you build your Cloud Run container.

it is vertexai in there and freshly downloaded, so it should be the latest, right?

Yes, but because the same code work locally and not on Cloud Run, I supposed it could be a difference between what you run locally and what run on Google Cloud. Do you use a custom service account on Cloud RUn?

Another question: Do you run the Cloud Run service in the same project as your Gemini endpoint (I mean, same as defined in this line vertexai.init(project="<PROJECT_ID", location="MY_REGION"))? If not, try to activate the gemini API in the Cloud Run service project

Thanks for taking the time. Indeed only one project and only one region at the time. Re service account, just using the custom one. I have “fixed” it by not using vertexai, but gemini API. My personal conclusion is that, in order to use vertex in the cloud, one needs to register a model in the Model Registry. What would be the difference otherwise between using vertexai and the gemini API?

Hi @regina_fallangi, Does this link1 and link2 helps you?

Thanks! Link1 was the issue before and then I fixed it. You can see the I-AM-Policy in the question. And re link2, that is not the error I am seeing, unfortunately.

Hi @regina_fallangi, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
